# What does Pearson correlation tell when features are uncorrelated

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, correlation, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have a dataset (31 features including the class). This dataset is about to be used for a classification problem. I thought to check the correlation between the features using Pearson correlation exists in `pandas`. When I set the Pearson's `threshold > 0.5`, I get the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("../dataset.csv")
cor = data.corr(method='pearson')
cor_target = abs(cor['Class'])
result = cor_target[cor_target > 0.5]
print(result)
```

The result is:

```
Class    1.0
Name: Class, dtype: float64
```

It turns out that all `30` features are not correlated at all. What does this mean? Is it always a good indicator that features are independent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumptions are somewhat wrong.

Take for an example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Class' : [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]})
cor = data.corr(method='pearson')
print(cor)
cor_target = abs(cor['Class'])
print(cor_target)
result = cor_target[cor_target > 0.5]
print(result)
```

```
              a         b     Class
a      1.000000  1.000000  0.288675
b      1.000000  1.000000  0.288675
Class  0.288675  0.288675  1.000000
a        0.288675
b        0.288675
Class    1.000000
Name: Class, dtype: float64
Class    1.0
Name: Class, dtype: float64
```

Feature set `a` and `b` are exactly the same, they have 1.0 correlation, but you'll still get only `1`.

Remove the class labels, and only observe the correlation between the intermediate features.

Observe the correlation matrix and select the ones with low correlation.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Class' : [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]})
cor = data[['a', 'b']].corr(method='pearson')
print(cor)
cor_target = abs(cor)
```

```
     a    b
a  1.0  1.0
b  1.0  1.0
```

If you want to use labels, try scikit-learn's feature importance, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html